# static div content change position

Tags: html, css

I have a header div which is absolute so I wanna make it static but if I do that the contents inside starts changing position on resizing window . what trick can I do to acheive a static header which do not move contents on window resize ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<head>
<title>Client  </title>

<style type="text/css">
.heading {position:fixed; visibility:show; width:100%;  left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index:3;
 border-bottom:5px solid #ccc; } 
 header{
 position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
    height: 60px !important;
    z-index:7;
    top: 0px;
}

/*My div position*/
.positioning-container{position:relative; 
width:1000px;  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 black solid; padding:0px;

   padding:60px 0 30px 0; 
  border-bottom:0px; padding:0px;
 background:#eee;}

.inner-container{position:relative; 
 background:#fff; padding:0px;
   padding:60px 0 30px 0; }
/*My div position*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="positioning-container">
<div class="inner-container" align = "center">
<header>
<div class= "heading" style="width:100% ; height:50px; background-color:#00A5C6">
<table id ="headertable" align="left"><tr><td>
<a href="index.php"><h2 class= "logo">Client Review</h2><td>&nbsp;</td></a></td><td>
<label>Search</label><input typ= "text"></td>
<td><a href="index.php" class="button middle">search</a></td>
<td><a href="login.php" class="button middle">Login</a></td>
<td><a href="register.php" class="button middle">Add Client</a></td>
<td><a href="logout.php" class="button middle">Logout</a></td>
<td align="left" class="profile"><img src="bhubezi/images/logos/nopic.png" width="50" 

height="40"></td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
</header>
<div class="content">
content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share yout code to get the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with relative and absolute positioning.  Keep in mind, when you position an item absolute it's absolute to the nearest relative position.

```
<div class="relative" style="position: relative">
<div class="absoluteItem" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
this content will sit on the bottom line of it's parent div (relative)
</div>

</div>
```

this content will remain seated when zooming in and out of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Static is the default position of elements. You can keep it from shifting on window resize by assigning a fixed pixel width to the container. If it's fluid, it's going to shift. If it's fixed, it won't.